# Insert links to images on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

This may seem stupid, but how can I insert links into images in Google sheets, when I'm using images from a server which resize to the row size while keeping their dimensions.

I'm using this to insert the images...

```
=image("http://www.scubadivingphuket.net/_images/spendmoney.jpg",1)
```

[image: Images I want to add links to]

And the link button isn't available.
[image: Greyed out link icon]

Any help appreciated, thanks. Must be something simple surely?

Thanks

Comment: You can assign a hyperlink to an image, like: `=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com";IMAGE("http://www.scubadivingphuket.net/_images/spendmoney.jpg"))`

Comment: Thanks. However, it seems to only insert the link, with no image. Any ideas?

Comment: I've searched online for help with this, and I'm going to say, I don't believe it's possible to do it this way. Shame though. Hope to be proved wrong about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IMAGE inside HYPERLINK

Example:

```
=hyperlink(
   "stackoverflow.com",
   image("http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=abcdef")
 )
```

Comment: Ruben, thanks! I'd found a not very elegant workaround, but now it's all good, and working properly thanks to you. At a glance, it was just changing the semi-colon to a comma?