# Issues Opening another Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Brand new to GAS coming from Excel.  I'm trying to write a simple script in Google Sheets that opens another spreadsheet but it doesn't do anything when triggered.  Code is below, any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance folks.

```
function openDoc() {

  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1uDAupXYzlUxLS5fG6ODzr3-MATYAfLMkAe2RjxOd9AE")

}
```

I've also tried the following with no success as well.

```
function openDoc() {

  var agent = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1uDAupXYzlUxLS5fG6ODzr3-MATYAfLMkAe2RjxOd9AE");
  return agent;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script can't open an spreadsheet to show it to the user. The openById method is used to create new spreadsheet object in order to be used by the code.

If you want that a spreadsheet be opened to show it to a user, your code could show them a link or other UI element then the user should click or tap on it.

To learn about custom UI on Google Sheets and other Google Apps, see [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)

Comment: Just to be sure that I understand, is there any way that I can assign the link to a drawing on the spreadsheet?

Comment: @ToddJordan That is another question, the short answer is no. Not exactly the same but this could helps: [Insert links to images on google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39252142/1595451)

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance, Ruben.  Have a great weekend.